# OutOfMemory error while Encrypting

Tags: java, android, encryption, out-of-memory

First off, this is the error I am getting

```
   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at coderaustin.com.FileEncryptor.encryptFile(FileEncryptor.java:56)
at coderaustin.com.Main.onCreate(Main.java:41)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Obviously I know what the error is, I just don't know how to avoid it. This is what my app does,

You select a file, and click Encrypt. So obviously from there it takes the file, and encrypts it using this code

```
try {
    FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
    FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(f.getAbsoluteFile() + ".des");

    PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(text.toCharArray());
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    SecretKey passwordKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    byte[] salt = new byte[8];
    Random rnd = new Random();
    rnd.nextBytes(salt);
    int iterations = 100;

    PBEParameterSpec paramaterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterations);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, passwordKey, paramaterSpec);

    outFile.write(salt);



    byte[] input = new byte[inFile.available()];

    int bytesRead;
     while ((bytesRead = inFile.read(input)) != -1)
                {
                  byte[] output = cipher.update(input, 0, bytesRead);
                   if (output != null) outFile.write(output);
               }

               byte[] output = cipher.doFinal();
               if (output != null) outFile.write(output);
               f.delete();
              inFile.close();
               outFile.flush();
               outFile.close();
```

Yes I know the code is pretty ugly, but it works. Any suggestions?

Thanks all :)

Edit: This is line 56

`byte[] input = new byte[inFile.available()];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Odd: if the file is very big I could see how that could be an issue. Why are you reading the entire file at once instead of reading it in small chunks and processing?

EDIT: try this.

```
byte[] input = new byte[4096];

    int bytesRead;
     while ((bytesRead = inFile.read(input, 0, 4096)) != -1)
                {
                  byte[] output = cipher.update(input, 0, bytesRead);
                   if (output != null) outFile.write(output);
               }
```

Comment: Wow I feel stupid, that's a really good point (and an obvious one I should have seen). So what would be my best option here? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Keep in mind that Android apps are limited in their heap sizes (usually 16 or 24MB), so any file bigger then that is going to be a problem even if you have hundreds of megabytes of memory free.

Comment: Thanks that worked great, and @sargas This should fix that even if they only have 16 or 24mb of heap size right? Since you are only loading 4096 bytes.

Comment: @Austin: I would increase the buffer size here to 64k or so, just because a larger buffer will be somewhat faster. Of course, testing to find out where the point of diminishing returns is on buffer size might be an idea.

Comment: Or use the [CipherOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) class with a BufferedOutputStream which does almost everything for you.